# If I move an entry to a different channel, will my associated Solspace Ratings move with it?

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

If I move an entry from one channel to another, will there be any problems with the Solspace Ratings attached to that entry moving along with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so, no. Rating stores its data in its own database table, indexed to each entry via `entry_id` only, so the channel that entry lives in should not matter.